# How to acces Canon PIXMA TS8351 in LAN on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, drivers, printing, canon, lan

I have a **Canon PIXMA TS8351** connected in LAN by WiFi to a router. I can access, print, and scan from different Windows computers but I don't know how to access the printer from a computer on **Ubuntu 18.04**.

On my Ubuntu computer, I've downloaded the following drivers that I found on the Canon website: **IJ Printer Driver v. 5.90 for Linux** and **ScanGear MP v. 3.90 for Linux**. I've tried to install the first but the installation failed because the printer is not detected.

However, with the **system-config-printer** command, when I connect to localhost, I can see the printer and the print of a test page works fine. But, when I go on Printers in the system settings, I get an error message telling something like (translation from French): "*Sorry! The printing service of the system does not seem to be available*".

I've tried to delete and reinstall **cups** but it doesn't produce any change.

Note: I've tried to put here some outputs from command line to give information that may help but AskUbuntu complains that "*This looks like spam*"...

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing IP address in /etc/cups/client.conf from

```
ServerName 172.16.x.xxx
```

to

```
ServerName 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Can you explain what the 172.16.x.xxx configuration was there for in the first place? Had you moved the computer to a different network or something?

Comment: Yes, I had moved the PC to a different network. If I recall correctly, an IT guy changed the IP configuration.